# Generating a maze with no open 2x2 rooms/spaces

Tags: java, algorithm, random, depth-first-search, maze

I'm trying to implement a maze generation algorithm in Java with a constraint where there should be no spaces in that maze of size 2x2 that are freely accessible. My implementation involves a 2D array, where each cell will either represent a wall ('#'), an accessible space (' '), an item to be collected ('$'), a hidden block (if not yet discovered yet by traversing maze; ('.')), or an enemy NPC ('!').

I have followed a maze algorithm described on Wikipedia as follows:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm

Under the recursive backtracker utilizing a stack:

> ```
> Choose the initial cell, mark it as visited and push it to the stack
> While the stack is not empty
>     Pop a cell from the stack and make it a current cell
>     If the current cell has any neighbours which have not been visited
>         Push the current cell to the stack
>         Choose one of the unvisited neighbours
>         Remove the wall between the current cell and the chosen cell
>         Mark the chosen cell as visited and push it to the stack
> ```

Example of how my maze would look normally:

```
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
# @     #                           ! #
#   #   #   # # # # # # #   #   # #   #
#       #       #           #         #
#   # # # # # # #   # # # # # # #     #
#       #                             #
# # #   #   # # # #     #   # # # #   #
#                                     #
#     # # #   # # #     # # # #   # # #
#             #                       #
#     # # #   # # #     # # #     #   #
#         #                 $         #
#   # #   # # #   # # #   # #   #     #
# !           #                     ! #
# # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #



    public class Maze {

        private final int ROWS = 15;
        private final int COLS = 20;
        private final int MAX_ROW = ROWS - 1;
        private final int MAX_COL = COLS - 1;
        private char wall = '#';
        private char cheese = '$';
        private char player = '@';
        private char hiddenCell = '.';
        private char catNPC = '!';
        private char availableSpace = ' ';
        private char deadPlayer = 'X';
        private Coordinate cheeseLocation;

        private Map<Coordinate, Boolean> visibleCellsToPlayer = new HashMap<>();
        private Map<Coordinate, Boolean> checkIfVisited = new HashMap<>();
        private Map<Coordinate, Character> mapForCompleteMaze = new HashMap<>();
        private Character[][] playerMaze = new Character[ROWS][COLS];
        private Character[][] completeMaze = new Character[ROWS][COLS];
        private List<Coordinate> listOfAllCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();


        public Maze() {
            this.mazeGenerate();
        }


public void mazeGenerate() {
    int rowIndex = 0;
    int colIndex = 0;

    while (rowIndex < ROWS) {
        while (colIndex < COLS) {
            Coordinate newCoordinate = new Coordinate(rowIndex, colIndex);
            completeMaze[rowIndex][colIndex] = wall;
            mapForCompleteMaze.put(newCoordinate, wall);
            visibleCellsToPlayer.put(newCoordinate, false);
            checkIfVisited.put(newCoordinate, false);
            listOfAllCoordinates.add(newCoordinate);
            colIndex++;
        }
        rowIndex++;
        colIndex = 0;
    }
    innerMaze();
    while (!ValidMaze()) {
        innerMaze();
    }
}


public void innerMaze() {
    List<Coordinate> listOfCoordinates = new ArrayList<>();
    Stack<Coordinate> DFS_Stack = new Stack();
    int directionToGo = 0;
    int currentXCoordinate = 0;
    int currentYCoordinate = 0;
    int adjacentCellX = 0;
    int adjacentCellY = 0;
    int deleteWallAtXCoordinate = 0;
    int deleteWallAtYCoordinate = 0;

    Coordinate initialCell = new Coordinate(1, 1);
    DFS_Stack.push(initialCell);

    while (!DFS_Stack.empty()) {
        Coordinate currentCoordinate = DFS_Stack.pop();
        currentXCoordinate = currentCoordinate.getRow();
        currentYCoordinate = currentCoordinate.getCol();

        if ((currentXCoordinate - 2) >= 1) {
            Coordinate up = findCoordinate((currentXCoordinate - 2), currentYCoordinate);
            if (checkIfVisited.get(up) != true) {
                up.setDirection('N');
                listOfCoordinates.add(up);
            }
        }
        if ((currentXCoordinate + 2) < MAX_ROW) {
            Coordinate down = findCoordinate((currentXCoordinate + 2), currentYCoordinate);
            if (checkIfVisited.get(down) != true) {
                down.setDirection('S');
                listOfCoordinates.add(down);
            }
        }
        if ((currentYCoordinate - 2) >= 1) {
            Coordinate left = findCoordinate(currentXCoordinate, (currentYCoordinate - 2));
            if (checkIfVisited.get(left) != true) {
                left.setDirection('W');
                listOfCoordinates.add(left);
            }
        }
        if ((currentYCoordinate + 2) < MAX_COL) {
            Coordinate right = findCoordinate(currentXCoordinate, (currentYCoordinate + 2));
            if (checkIfVisited.get(right) != true) {
                right.setDirection('E');
                listOfCoordinates.add(right);
            }
        }
        if ((currentYCoordinate + 2) == MAX_COL) {
            Coordinate right = findCoordinate(currentXCoordinate, (currentYCoordinate + 1));
            if (checkIfVisited.get(right) != true) {
                right.setDirection('E');
                listOfCoordinates.add(right);
            }
        }
        if (!listOfCoordinates.isEmpty()) {
            DFS_Stack.push(currentCoordinate);
            directionToGo = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, listOfCoordinates.size());
            Coordinate coordinateOfDirection = listOfCoordinates.get(directionToGo);
            char directionFromCurrentCell = coordinateOfDirection.getDirection();
            Coordinate wallToDelete;

            if (directionFromCurrentCell == 'N') {
                wallToDelete = findCoordinate((currentXCoordinate - 1), currentYCoordinate);
            } else if (directionFromCurrentCell == 'S') {
                wallToDelete = findCoordinate((currentXCoordinate + 1), currentYCoordinate);
            } else if (directionFromCurrentCell == 'W') {
                wallToDelete = findCoordinate(currentXCoordinate, (currentYCoordinate - 1));
            } else {
                wallToDelete = findCoordinate(currentXCoordinate, (currentYCoordinate + 1));
            }

            adjacentCellX = wallToDelete.getRow();
            adjacentCellY = wallToDelete.getCol();
            completeMaze[adjacentCellX][adjacentCellY] = availableSpace;

            deleteWallAtXCoordinate = coordinateOfDirection.getRow();
            deleteWallAtYCoordinate = coordinateOfDirection.getCol();
            completeMaze[deleteWallAtXCoordinate][deleteWallAtYCoordinate] = availableSpace;

            checkIfVisited.put(coordinateOfDirection, true);
            checkIfVisited.put(wallToDelete, true);
            listOfCoordinates.clear();
            DFS_Stack.push(coordinateOfDirection);
        }
    }
}
```

I have included various samples of the code that I have written, however the gist of it is my Maze class constructor will call mazeGenerate(), which will generate a maze with a wall present in every cell. From this stage, innerMaze() will be called, which is the algorithm mentioned on the Wikipedia. My code will then run a check to see if any 2x2 squares exist (ValidMaze()) on the now completed maze, and if it returns as false, it will continue to regenerate a maze until a proper maze has been created.

I am wondering whether it is my logic is flawed, my implementation is utterly incorrect, or if my error checking is invalid. I would highly appreciate any help with this problem and I am thankful for any contributions made. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The described algorithm will not create any free 2×2 spaces unless you remove additional walls. Your code just shows the implementation of the maze creation. Don't you get the expected results? (By the way, you have two cases where you go east. The case where you just go one pace might offset the rest f the maze.)

Comment: I have now looked a bit more into this. If you remove the second "east" case, where you just go one pace and the maze looks as it should.